# Service starts without any obvious reason

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have another problem with a service, which is started "randomly".
Those lines of code should start it every day at 3:15.
Although it does start at this time, it is also executed at 10:53 or 9:46. I just don't know why.

```
PendingIntent aintent = PendingIntent.getService(this,  0, a, 0);
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
if(gc.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)>3)
   gc.add(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,3);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE, 15);
am.cancel(aintent);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, gc.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, aintent);
```

Do you have any suggestions?

EDIT:

Like suggested I changed the method of executing the services. They do now get started by a broadcast receiver, this does work fine.
But somehow, the UploadData Service still starts without any reason and I cant figure out why. I put a Log message in the Receiver, so everytime it gets called, I get a message. But it did not get called. What could be the issue here? Is there any way to find out, what started the upload in the first place?

Comment: Do not use a service directly with a `_WAKEUP` alarm. Use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` or [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful). Beyond that, use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to ensure that you do not have multiple alarms scheduled.

Comment: Just to be sure, I am on the right path:
_WAKEUP means, that the device will wakeup from the deepsleep, so that it executes the start in any case, no matter in which state the device is, except turned off of course?

Comment: Your interpretation of `_WAKEUP` is correct.